# Xcode4: Does every library in an app have to have the same configurations as the app itself?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Say I have an app "FooApp" that depends on library "BarLib."

"FooApp" has several configurations: Debug, Release, AdHoc, AppStore, Profile, Distribution, etc. ...

"LibBar" has only two: Debug and Release.

Is there a way to map FooApp's configurations to the more limited set of configurations in LibBar?

Or do I have to encourage the team who owns LibBar to add more configurations? (doable but sucky)

Thanks!